# How to either resize a div and move it or slide to hidden div?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, move

I have a layout set up with my links as images for 4 of them 320x320px. They have a opacity change on hover. What i am looking to do now it either on click the box will expand to a pre-determined size with new content if at all possible. If not then navigate to a hidden div on the same page with the new content. Hope this makes sense.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Adam Sackfield's Portfolio</title>

<script src="scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("nav a").hover(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 300);
                    }, function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        opacity: 0.3
                    }, 300);
                });
            });
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<header>

    <div id="logo">

        <img src="images/logoarrows.jpg">

    </div><!-- Logo Close -->

    <div id="social">

    </div><!-- Social Close -->

</header>

<nav>
    <a href="#" class="yellow"><p class="yelinner">Home</p></a>
    <a href="#" class="pink"><p class="pinkinner">About Me</p></a>
    <a href="#" class="purple"><p class="purpinner">Portfolio</p></a>
    <a href="#" class="green"><p class="greinner">Contact Me</p></a>     
</nav>

<section>

    <article>

    </article>

    <aside>

    </aside>

</section>

<footer>

</footer>

</div><!-- Wrapper Close -->

</body>
</html>

CSS

*           {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
                                    }


#wrapper    {   
                width: 800px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                background-color: #000000;
                                    }

header      {
                width:1000px;
                height: 220px;


                                    }

#wrapper header #logo {
                width: 400px;
                padding-left: 200px;


                                    }

body        {
              background: #111111;
              color: #FFF;
              font-family:’Open Sans’, sans-serif;
              font-weight: 300;
              font-size: 16pt;
                                    }
a           {
              color: #FFF;
              text-decoration: none;
                                    }

nav         {
              width: 800px;
              margin-top: 60px;
              padding-left: 75px;

                                    }

#wrapper nav a  {
              width: 320px;
              line-height: 320px;             
              display: inline-block;
              margin: 4px;                    
              opacity: 0.3;
              text-align: center;

                                }
.yellow     {       background-image: url(../images/tiles/yellow.jpg);
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;
                      }


.purple     {       background-image: url(../images/tiles/purple.jpg);
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;
                                                   }


.pink       {       background-image: url(../images/tiles/pink.jpg);
                    background-repeat:no-repeat;
                    }

.green      {       background-image: url(../images/tiles/green.jpg);
                    background-repeat:no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.dropdownstuff {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display:none;
}
.Showstuff {
    display:block !important; 
}
</style>
<script>
$("nav a").onClick(function() {
    n = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.dropdownstuff.Showstuff').removeClass('Showstuff');
    $('.dropdownstuff.'+n).addClass('Showstuff'); 
});

$("a.dropdownhider").onClick(function() {
    $('.dropdownstuff.Showstuff').removeClass('Showstuff');
});
</script>
```

Then you have some divs below or inside your dropdowns:

```
<a href="#" class="yellow"><p class="yelinner">Home</p></a>        
<a href="#" class="pink"><p class="pinkinner">About Me</p></a>
<a href="#" class="purple"><p class="purpinner">Portfolio</p></a>
<a href="#" class="green"><p class="greinner">Contact Me</p></a> 

<div class="dropdownstuff yellow"><a href="#" class="dropdownhider">Hide this</a></div>
<div class="dropdownstuff pink"><a href="#" class="dropdownhider">Hide this</a></div>
<div class="dropdownstuff purple"><a href="#" class="dropdownhider">Hide this</a></div>
<div class="dropdownstuff green"><a href="#" class="dropdownhider">Hide this</a></div>
```

Upon clicking on of your links, it uses it's class to determine which of the divs to unhide.

Edit: Now the divs should fill the screen. When you click on the links, the div content will appear by having the class. Not sure exactly what you want with animation though.

Comment: This is very useful stuff thanks man. for the class can i have this div appear on top of the prev page or will it move the over items all over the place?

Comment: The div can be anywhere on the website you want, they don't need to be `div`s either. They can be `span` or `a` or `li`. As for what they do to your site, there's tons of things that can happen and it all depends on your css and html layout. From the looks of it, you have 4 giant buttons and you want each one to make the entire page be covered in a new screen, right?

Comment: Thats exactly correct. So whether 2 animate off to the left and 2 for the right. Or the new page just appears over the top of them slight opaque. Something like that.

Comment: OK, now it should work by filling the screen with the div. The front page links are clicked, the class that shows the div is added. When you click on the link inside the div, the class is removed from all divs (just in case, but you can customize it however you want). As far as look and styling, that's all css. For animation, you'll have to play with the timing and such.

You can replace `.addClass` with some sort of animation, and same with `.removeClass`.

Comment: Thanks alot mate this is perfect i will have a mess around with it now see what i can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onClick event to call a javascript or jQuery function then have that function alter the css or html as needed

```
<div onClick="yourFunction()"></div>


<script>

function yourFunction(){

//this will change your background color on click

//JS
document.getElementById("divID").style.background ="blue";

//jQuery 
$(".className").css("background-color","yellow");

}


</script>
```

for JS reference
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

for jQuery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp

Comment: Could you explain how to do this please. Not too clued up on jQuery and cant seem to find the correct phrase for a Google query.

Comment: Thinking about it would i create a seperate class for the specified div then have scripts change the class to the larger box onclick

Answer (score 0):

You can use on click event to increase the width and add the content to it

```
jQuery('body').on('click','nav a',function(){
    jQuery(this).animate({width: "200px"}, 500).append("any-content");
})
```

Your motive is still unclear, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the response. So just to be clear in the .append("any-content") i can put all the html tags i may need like p ul and such like. Then add a back button to the main menu?

Comment: tried to vote up this answer but wont allow as reputation is too low.

Comment: @user2682597 you can mark the answer as correct.if you found it correct

Comment: Yes you can append anything, HTML tags or whatever you would like to, and yes you can mark as answer if it solves ur problem.